# Is there a proper acronym for Sql Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, acronym

I know that for the full edition of Sql Server it is readily understood as MSSQS or simply SQS, is there a corresponding acronym for the Express edition?

Comment: Googling for MSSQS produces 2430 results, which is basically nothing.

Comment: MSSQS?  Never heard of that.  And Google seems to agree.  What the heck is the last S for?  I think the most widely held one for sql server is MSSQL.  I don't think there is one for express.  But I think MSSEX would be pretty cool.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev apparently Google is better at finding it as "MS SQS", (at) (wtf am I forced to do this for?)Will Server

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of "MSSQS" being an acronym for anything. I've pretty much just heard MSSQL and, if the specific version is needed, then it's said.

Answer (score 2):

Neither MSSQS nor SQS gives any Google hits for SQL Server. MSSQL is the most common abbreviation, although Microsoft never abbreviates the product name, so MSSQL is strictly a community thing.

Also, there is no "full" edition, there are Enterprise, Standard, Developer [etc.](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions.aspx) So even "MSSQL" is ambiguous, as you can see here on Stackoverflow from the numerous MSSQL questions that do not mention the edition (or even version).

Comment: See my comment to Anton Gogolev, google is actually being poor at finding the results correctly.

Comment: Hmm, well if I search for "MS SQS" Google says "Showing results for MS SQL" and when I force a search for "MS SQS" I get no hits at all about SQL Server. Do you have any links to pages that specifically refer to SQL Server as "MS SQS"?

Comment: After the first few search results for "MS SQS" the results show usage of it as that: http://www.scrumdesk.com/customers/testimonials/ is one of the first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a concrete acronym for SQL Server Express edition, but if you want to use the instance name of a SQL Server Express instance you could always use 'SQLEXPRESS'.